# How I can store url in database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In laravel 5.4 , When I want to use url I've to config in web.php
ex

```
Route::get('/test/{id}', function () {
    return view('frontend/test/{id}');
});
```

Is their anyway to store path into database and use It with out maunal config in web.php

for example I want to change `/test/1, /test/2 to test/test1 , test/test2`

which I can Update delete in database In my database I've url path

```
test1

test2
```

Comment: Why do you want to store it in the database? You have to manually config a connection to the database too. Not really seeing the benefit here.

Comment: You'd need to add a name field within the database of which would hold names test1 etc. and then rather than `/{{ $variable->id }}` you'd just do `{{ $variable->name }}` and change route from `/{id}` to `/{name}`

Comment: well, I want to change name in view.blade /1 , /2 . to /test1 ,/test2 because sometimes my customers don't want to use /1 ,/2 and they want to use thier name in url and I never try this before =]

Comment: Are you storing the name within the database?

Comment: yes, In my database I've field name url  @Option

Comment: can you give me some example of route  in web.php ?

Comment: If the name is stored, just change the <a href= to the named field rather than the id and then do the same within the routes file.

Comment: @Option well, LOL why i dont think about this haha thank you

Comment: @test1321, added it as an answer for you so others who are also stuck can review the correct method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name is stored within the database simply change:

`<a href="link/{{ $variable->id }}` to `<a href="link/{{ $variable->name }}`

Then change your route from:

```
Route::get('/test/{id}', function () {
    return view('frontend/{id}');
});
```

to

```
Route::get('/test/{name}', function () {
    return view('frontend/{name}');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

save hard core the url in your controller and update the id dynamically from controller

Comment: can you give my some example ?